# How can I detect if the atomic `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` feature is supported by my C compiler?

Tags: c, atomic

I want to use `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` in my C programs.

How can I detect that the compiler supports this extension?

Comment: Is this question about detecting `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` by a distributed build configuration? Otherwise, this question seems a bit trivial.

Comment: I need to know this for configure build the program.

Comment: Thought so. @andrew's comment suggests though that the answer would be the same: compile a dummy and check for success.

Answer (score 3):

Write a short program that uses it and try to compile it. If it compiles- you are good to go.

Comment: I assumed compiling the app will take longer. Also for the whole app compilation may fail for a different reason. Best option is to write as small an app as possible to isolate the test.

Comment: Although this might sound like a flippant answer, it really is the only reliable way to do it. That’s what [autotools](http://nostarch.com/autotools.htm) does, enabling GCC and all the GNU utilities to build on every obscure operating system and platform in existence.

Comment: I need to know this for configure build the program.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Actually you can compile, error will occur during linking.

Comment: actually it may fail in both phases.